# SharePoint 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

We have Oracle 11g base HR System. Now our requirement is to make some workflow on SharePoint 2010. So we comeup to the decission that we will make webpart to insert, update and retrive records from Oracle and then we will start workflow on that.

So my question was, is it possible to start workflow without is list or document library. If yes than how can I get some idea on that. Some URL where I can find more details.

Kindly let me know if I am going in wrong direction. Please help on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have site level workflows in SharePoint 2010 which can run without list or a library.

See:

http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3910746/Using-SiteLevel-Workflows-in-SharePoint-2010.htm

However, there is not much information available in the question to evaluate weather its the right option or not. It depends on what is the workflow requirement etc.